# C Preprocessor treating an identifier as object-like instead of function-like

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

This is a very simplified version of some code I just ran into at work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define F(G) G(1)
#define G(x) x+1

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", F(G));
}
```

prints 2.

Now, I can see that F(G) expands to G(1) and then G(1) expands to 2, but its not clear to me why.  I would have expected to get an error that G is not a function from the printf line.

How does the pre-processor parse code like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function-like macro is only invoked if its name is followed by a `(`.

In `F(G)`, `G` is not followed by a `(`, so the `G` there is not a macro invocation.

In `F(G) G(1)`, `G` is a macro parameter and thus is not macro-replaced directly (this is a very confusing macro you've got :-O).  In `G(1)`, `G` is replaced by the argument corresponding to the parameter `G`, which also happens to be `G`.  That replacement is then *rescanned* and `G(1)` is evaluated to `1 + 1`.

If we rewrite your macros so that you aren't using `G` in multiple different ways, it's far easier to understand:

```
#define F(x) x(1)
#define G(x) x + 1
```

Here, `F(G)` is replaced by `G(1)`.  This is then rescanned, and the invocation of `G` is evaluated, yielding `1 + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on James McNellis' answer, the C99 standard prescribes:

> 6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement
>
> 1 After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and # and ##
>   processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. Then, the
>   resulting preprocessing token sequence is rescanned, along with all subsequent
>   preprocessing tokens of the source ﬁle, for more macro names to replace.
>
> 2 If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list
>   (not including the rest of the source ﬁle’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced.
>   Furthermore, if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced,
>   it is not replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer
>   available for further replacement even if they are later (re)examined in contexts in which
>   that macro name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced.
>
> 3 The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed
>   as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, but all pragma unary operator
>   expressions within it are then processed as speciﬁed in 6.10.9 below.

Answer (score 0):

#defines do very basic string replacement:

printf("%d\n", F(G));

goes to

printf("%d\n", G(1));

which goes to:

printf("%d\n", 1+1);

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor makes one pass, but you are thinking that it makes one pass per #define.  So during its pass the preprocessor matches and replaces `F(G)` but doesn't match any `G(x)`.

Comment: Preprocessing is done in a single pass through the file, but a particular macro invocation may involve multiple, nonrecursive passes.